# Batch problem copying text from one file to another without blank spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having a weird problem. I thought my code worked 3 days ago and I'm pretty sure about that one. But since yesterday it gives me errors, while nothing has changed in the source code.

I want to copy the text in a textfile to another text file but without the blank spaces. So if my original textfile has 3 blankspaces (so lines only containing tabs or " "), there should be 0 in the new file. This is my code:

```
REM Create a Copy of the File without blank spaces
for /F "delims=" %%J in (%SrcFile%) do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set row=%%J
    if defined row echo.!row!>>%SrcFile%Backup.bak
endLocal
```

But in the Backup file it still gives me blank spaces, even though I thought they are eliminated by the 'if defined row' part. I can't seem to understand what's the problem here, because I thought that `for /f` skips blank spaces?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code does not attempt to remove whitespace at all, so I do not understand how the source code cannot have changed if the script worked three days ago. `For /F` doesn't output empty lines!

Comment: I thought it worked, but yeah as we can see it does not. For /f does not yeah, but with the delims part it does. The Problem with using it without delims is, that it removes all blank spaces and there are some lines in the document such as test : true { and then we will have this deleted, thats why I dont think that For /f is possible here?

Comment: You seem to be confused about the entire `For /F` construct. Using `"Delims="` as you have will mean that your output should only have empty lines and any which begin with a semicolon, **`;`**, removed from the output. Perhaps, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56162139/edit), to properly explain what your task is, so that we can better advise on the appropriate methods.

Comment: Yeah, as I said I want to have the blank spaces (empty lines, lines with only spaces or tabs) removed in the output file, that is exactly what my goal is?

Comment: If the line contains spaces or tabs it isn't empty, you'll need to specifically remove spaces as part of the loop, e.g `Set "row=!row: =!"`, should work to remove all spaces from every line, but I don't think that's your intention. If you provide us with before and after content examples, we may be able to advise appropriately on what you need.

Comment: I cant access any pastebin sites currently. I would really like to give you an example basically something like:    },         
   "GpuSpeed" : {     
      "gpuSpeed0" : 948,                        ,                    ,              ... Where the two last parts are "blank spaces" and they should be deleted in the new File. Hope it is somehow understandable, sorry.

Comment: Your question needs a complete rewrite then, because my answer was to output all lines which were not, `empty lines` or `lines with only spaces or tabs`, as in your comment above. It seems as if you're wanting to remove any trailing spaces or tabs from any line or possibly only those which follow a comma! I've already asked you to please provide us with before and after content examples, we may be able to advise appropriately on what you need, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56162139/edit) and do so.

Comment: A complete rewrite at this point would invalidate already existing (correct to the quesition as now) answers. Better ask a new (better) question.

Comment: And i already told you that i dont have acess to any sites such as pastebin etc. right now so I cant reformat the before after correctly which would just make it more complicated. I want to keep trailing spaces or tabs , they are okay. But in the File there are some lines which are just linebreaks and nothing more. just hitting enter a few times produces them, and those are the ones I want to remove

Answer (score 1):

The task may be peformed more simply, *subject to its tricky conditions*, by simply using [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr):

```dos
FindStr /RC:"[^     ]" "source.txt">"new.txt"
```

Where the content between the brackets is **<kbd>^</kbd>                            <kbd>TAB</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already have an more specific and working FindStr. findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^[\ \ ]*$" "file.txt" >> "file.tmp"     I just thought I could do it with a simpe for /f loop

Comment: @Chrisi0805, I do not understand what your comment means with regard being more specific, my code is much simpler and does exactly what you need it to do, hence the reason I posted it! It specifically outputs every line which contains any character other than spaces or tabs, _(this excludes: **1.** empty lines, **2.** lines with only spaces, **3.** lines with only tabs **4.** lines with any combination of only spaces and tabs)_. Additionally, if you already had that line, you wouldn't have asked your question. I think you meant that you've improved on my code, which you haven't!

Comment: I had the line when I asked the question, but I wanted to do it with a for loop. Back to your FindStr: Atleast in my case and my input file, it does not delete a the combination of tabs and spaces, which my comment does

Comment: @Chrisi0805, if you don't want to give anybody upvotes, acceptance or credit for an answer which specifically does what you've asked, then don't, but please don't waste our time trying to justify your lack of gratitude. Given you last comment, here's what your question should really have said, "I am currently using `findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^[\ \ ]*$" "file.txt" >> "file.tmp"` to remove empty lines, those containing one or more spaces only and those containing one or more tabs only. Can this performed using a `For` loop, instead of using `FindStr` or `Find`? Thank you." That wasn't difficult!

Comment: I'am not entirely sure why you get angry right now. Yes, you are right that I should have formulated the question like this, I am sorry about that one. I would give you credit or acceptance or upvotes or whatever you want to, but first of all: I can't? Second: The versions you gave me didnt work (yes, thats probably because I did not show you a before/after, but i actually cant give it to you in a proper way...). Thanks for your help and your advice, ill keep it in mind for my next question :)

Comment: @Chrisi0805, regarding acceptance, **yes you can**, it is a simple matter of clicking on the large grayed out check mark to the left of your chosen solution! As far as the before and after content was concerned, you could have used the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56162139/edit) facility and pasted it into your question, formatting it in exactly the same way as you did with your code.

Comment: @Chrisi0805 - There is no reason to ever use FOR /F if FINDSTR can do the job. FINDSTR is much much faster than even the most simple FOR /F loop. And FINDSTR tends to be much simpler given all the coding hoops that typically must be gone through in order to make a FOR /F loop bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

As Compo already noted, a line containing spaces and/or tabs isn't empty.

Take each line, remove any spaces and any tabs. If anything is left, print the whole line.

The trick is the very first `set` command: `set "row=%%a<SPACE><TAB>"` to give the following `set` commands at least something to remove (else you end with `<SPACE>=` or `<TAB>=` instead of an empty string)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set "row=%%a  "
  set "row=!row: =!"
  set "row=!row:    =!"
  if defined row echo\%%a
)
```

Comment: I tried that, but that will just remove spaces and tabs where other text is. The thing is, the "empty" lines (i know they are not empty but they dont have any content besides a linebreak) are still there.

Comment: yes, `row` has spaces and tabs removed, but I use it only to check. Output is `%%a` (the whole line). Edited to keep leading spaces/tabs. Anyway - @Compo's solution is much simpler, much faster and much more safe.